# Conversion constructor won't convert "2" into user-defined-type in operator +

Tags: c++, casting, operator-overloading, overloading

I have a class called Fraction :

```
#ifndef FRACTION_H
#define FRACTION_H

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Fraction
{
  // data
  int m_iNom;
  int m_iDenom;

  // operations
  int gcd (int i, int j);
  void reduce ();

public:

 Fraction (int nn=0, int dn=1); // 1 declaration = 3 constructors
 Fraction (const Fraction& fr); //C.Ctor
 ~Fraction (); //Dtor
 Fraction& operator = (const Fraction &fr); //assignment

 Fraction& operator ++ (); // prefix - ++a
  const Fraction operator ++ (int); // postfix - a++

  friend const Fraction operator + (const Fraction &f1, const Fraction &f2);
  friend const Fraction operator - (const Fraction &f1, const Fraction &f2);
  friend const Fraction operator * (const Fraction &f1, const Fraction &f2);
  friend const Fraction operator / (const Fraction &f1, const Fraction &f2);

 Fraction& operator += (const Fraction &f);

  operator double () { return double (m_iNom) / m_iDenom; } //casting operator

  friend istream& operator >> (istream &is, Fraction &f);
  friend ostream& operator << (ostream &os, const Fraction &f);
  const int& operator[] (int i) const;
  int& operator [] (int i);


};
#endif
```

with the next implementation file :

```
#include "Fraction.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


Fraction::Fraction (int nn, int dd) :
   m_iNom (nn), m_iDenom (dd) {
  if (m_iDenom == 0)
  m_iDenom = 1;
 reduce ();
 cout<<"Ctor - Fraction: "<<m_iNom<<"/"<<m_iDenom<<endl;
}


Fraction::Fraction (const Fraction & fr){
 m_iNom=fr.m_iNom;
 m_iDenom=fr.m_iDenom;
 cout<<"C.Ctor - Fraction: "<<m_iNom<<"/"<<m_iDenom<<endl;
}

Fraction::~Fraction() {
 cout<<"del: "<<m_iNom<<"/"<<m_iDenom<<endl;
}


int Fraction::gcd (int i, int j) {
  if ((i == 0) || (j == 0))
   return i + j;
  while (i %= j) {
   int t = i;
  i = j;
  j = t;
 }
  return j;
}


void Fraction::reduce () {
  int g = gcd (m_iNom, m_iDenom);
 m_iNom /= g;
 m_iDenom /= g;
}


const Fraction operator + (const Fraction &f1, const Fraction &f2) {
  int nn = f1.m_iNom * f2.m_iDenom + f1.m_iDenom * f2.m_iNom;
  int dd = f1.m_iDenom * f2.m_iDenom;
  return Fraction (nn, dd);
}


const Fraction operator - (const Fraction &f1, const Fraction &f2) {
  int nn = f1.m_iNom * f2.m_iDenom - f1.m_iDenom * f2.m_iNom;
  int dd = f1.m_iDenom * f2.m_iDenom;
  return Fraction (nn, dd);
}


const Fraction operator * (const Fraction &f1, const Fraction &f2) {
  int nn = f1.m_iNom * f2.m_iNom;
  int dd = f1.m_iDenom * f2.m_iDenom;
  return Fraction (nn, dd);
}


const Fraction operator / (const Fraction &f1, const Fraction &f2) {
  int nn = f1.m_iNom * f2.m_iDenom;
  int dd = f1.m_iDenom * f2.m_iNom;
  return Fraction (nn, dd);
}


Fraction& Fraction::operator = (const Fraction &f)
{
 m_iNom = f.m_iNom;
 m_iDenom = f.m_iDenom;
 cout<<"OP = - Fraction: "<<m_iNom<<"/"<<m_iDenom<<endl;
  return *this;
}


Fraction& Fraction::operator += (const Fraction &f) {
 (*this) = (*this) + f;
  return *this;
}


Fraction& Fraction::operator ++ ()
{
 m_iNom += m_iDenom;
 reduce ();
  return *this;
}


const Fraction Fraction::operator ++ (int)
{
  int nn = m_iNom;
  int dd = m_iDenom;
 m_iNom += m_iDenom;
 reduce ();
  return Fraction (nn, dd);
}


istream& operator >> (istream &is, Fraction &frac)
{
  char divSign;
 is >> frac.m_iNom >> divSign >> frac.m_iDenom;
  if (frac.m_iDenom == 0)
  frac.m_iDenom = 1;
 frac.reduce ();
  return is;
}


ostream& operator << (ostream& os, const Fraction &frac)
{
  return os << frac.m_iNom << "/" << frac.m_iDenom;
}


int& Fraction::operator [] (int i){
 cout<<"reg []"<<endl;
  if (i==1)
   return m_iNom;
  return m_iDenom;
}


const int& Fraction::operator[] (int i) const{
 cout<<"const []"<<endl;
  if (i==1)
   return m_iNom;
  return m_iDenom;
}
```

and I'm trying to do the action  **Fraction f4=f2+2;** but I get the following compiler error:

```
..\main.cpp:13: error: ambiguous overload for 'operator+' in 'f2 + 2'
..\main.cpp:13: note: candidates are: operator+(double, int) <built-in>
..\Fraction.h:27: note:                 const Fraction operator+(const Fraction&, const Fraction&)
```

But how could that be , if I have a conversion Constructor (please notice the Ctor in the .h file with the default values) with one argument which is suppose to convert the "2" into a Fraction ...then what's might the be the problem ?

thanks 
Ronen

Edit :

here's the main file (if it would help)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include "Fraction.h"

int main() {
    Fraction f1(1,2);
    Fraction f2(2);
    Fraction f3;

    Fraction f4=f2+2;  // problem's here 
    f2+f2;
    Fraction f5=f2-f1+f4;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 12 questions asked, and not a single anwer has been accepted!!

Comment: I fail to understand your meaning ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is:

```
operator double ()
```

defined inside your `Fraction` class.

While evaluating,

```
Fraction f4=f2+2;
```

Compiler has 2 choices:

**First Choice:**

The compiler can convert `f2` to a `double` using your provided operator function and then it can be used to call the inbuilt operator function:

```
    operator+(double, int);
```

**Second Choice:**

The compiler can convert `2` to a object of `Fraction` using constructor and then call:

```
const Fraction operator+(const Fraction&, const Fraction&)
```

The two choices cause an ambiguity and then the compiler complains and reports it to you.

**Solution:**
Change the name of the `double` operator function.

Comment: Other solutions include: 1. make the double() operator explicit if you're using a C++0x compiler. 2. Add a operator+(const Fraction&, double). There may be others too...

Comment: @Michael: Solution 3: don't use conversion operators without them being `explicit` (which means not using them pre C++0x).

Answer (score 3):

The compiler can't decide whether to convert `f2` to `double` then add `double` and `int`, or to construct Fraction from `2` then add two fractions.

Options:

- Make operator double() explicit (C++11)
- Overload operator + to take ints

Answer (score 1):

The compiler can indeed make 2 choices when you write something like `f2+2`.

- It can first convert 2 to a fraction by using the fraction's constructor and then use the Fraction's + operator.
- It can first convert f2 to a double using the Fraction's double operator, and then simply add the double and the integer

You will have to make either the constructor explicit, or give the double-operator an explicit name (e.g. toDouble) to solve the problem.